# Notify binding for static properties in static classes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I found a notify property changed example for **static** properties in **static** class. but it doesn't update any changes in TextBlock. Here are the codes.

First binding is working with the "test" string in constructor but StaticPropertyChanged is always null.

```
public static class InteractionData
{
    public static List<string> SelectedDirectories { get; set; }
    private static string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public static string ErrorMessgae
    {
        get { return errorMessage; }
        set
        {
            errorMessage = value;
            NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("errorMessage");
        }
    }

    static InteractionData()
    {
        SelectedDirectories = new List<string>();
        errorMessage = "test";
    }

    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
    private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (StaticPropertyChanged != null)
            StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In View ...

```
     xmlns:error ="clr-namespace:CopyBackup.Providers"
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static error:InteractionData.ErrorMessgae} ,Mode=OneWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Wherever I change the property, TextBlock doesn't update.

Appreciate

Comment: I see no mention of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your code... And why do you have `OneWay` set?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Static property change notification is a new pattern in WPF 4.5. See here: http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties

Comment: Your title speaks about `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which is not the case here. You never use it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman INotifyPropertyChanged  doesn't work with static classes. And I wrote about Notify for static objects not INotifyPropertyChanged. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Clemens the link was the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Parham.D Your actual problem was the wrong property name, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Clemens edited your title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similar to an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, [static property change notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#static_properties) only works if you use the correct property name when firing the `StaticPropertyChanged` event.

Use the property name, not the name of the backing field:

```
public static string ErrorMessgae
{
    get { return errorMessage; }
    set
    {
        errorMessage = value;
        NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("ErrorMessgae"); // not "errorMessage"
    }
}
```

You should certainly also fix the misspelled property name:

```
public static string ErrorMessage
{
    get { return errorMessage; }
    set
    {
        errorMessage = value;
        NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("ErrorMessage");
    }
}
```

The binding should look like this:

```
Text="{Binding Path=(error:InteractionData.ErrorMessage)}"
```

See [this blog post](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties) for details about static property change notification.

---

You may also avoid to write property names at all by using the `CallerMemberNameAttribute`:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
...

public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(
    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

You could now call the method without explicitly specifying the property name:

```
NotifyStaticPropertyChanged();
```

Comment: I think the class also needs to implement INotifyPropertChanged, so class cant be static. Im not sure if this works though

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That is not necessary. Please take a look at the blog post linked in the answer.

Comment: @Clemens I corrected the property name, but it still didn't work. Then, when I used the sample codes in the link, it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Nevertheless the code in my answer shows a working solution for static property change notification, and hence answers your question (in other words, solves your problem). You should therefore simply accept it.