# Is there a way to refresh the WPF UI so that all the texts update with a new value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

In my WPF app, I have a class with Static strings as follows and I refer the same from the XAML. My intention is to update these static strings and the UI texts should reflect the update.

```
public class StaticStrings
{
    public static string text1= "sample 1";
    public static string text2= "sample 2";
    public static string text3= "sample 3";
}
```

From the XAML I refer them as below:

```
<Label 
                    Content="{x:Static local:StaticStrings.text1}" 
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    Margin="5,0,18,3"
                    />
<Button x:Name="btn" 
                    Click="btn_MouseUp"
                    ToolTip="{x:Static local:StaticStrings.text2}"
                    />
```

During runtime, I would update the texts of `StaticStrings` and wish to see them reflected in the UI. How to achieve this?

Comment: I'd suggest you look a bit more into Data Binding instead

Comment: Will Data Binding help in updating content dynamically? @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos

Comment: The whole point of DataBinding is that it will dynamically update UI if the data changes.

Comment: See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64952025/1136211

Comment: also, using mutable global state like that is [not a good practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

Answer (score 1):

1. Modify your `StaticString` class to support change notifications and expose public properties to bind to:

   ```
    public class StaticStrings
    {
        private static string text1 = "sample 1";
        public static string Text1
        {
            get { return text1; }
            set { text1 = value; NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private static string text2 = "sample 2";
        public static string Text2
        {
            get { return text2; }
            set { text2 = value; NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private static string text3 = "sample 3";
        public static string Text3
        {
            get { return text3; }
            set { text3 = value; NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

        private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
   ```
2. Bind to the public properties:

   ```
    <Label 
            Content="{Binding Path=(local:StaticStrings.Text1)}" 
            Background="Transparent" 
            Margin="5,0,18,3"
            />
    <Button x:Name="btn" 
            Click="btn_MouseUp"
            ToolTip="{Binding Path=(local:StaticStrings.Text2)}"
            />
   ```

Comment: The thing is the strings can be any number. This seems really tiresome. Is there a way to trigger the PropertyChanged event automatically for all the props.

Comment: [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) injects code which raises the `PropertyChanged` event into property setters of classes which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` at build time. Don't know if it works with static properties. Otherwise you will have to implement these by your own like I did in my example. This is nothing strange or unusal.