# Xaml bindings don't update (and everything seems like it should work)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've been working on a unique kind of project for a while now and recently I've written a custom "binding system"(for external code) which works great, however today I needed to get some MVVM style bindings to work(for internal UI). After an entire day of googling and trying different things, I still don't have an answer or working code. I'm almost at a point where I'll just add "normal" bindings to my existing binding system and call it a day.

***anyway... my question...***

I'm trying to make a **one-way binding** from a **ViewModel class to a UI element**. There is are some "rules" I have to conform to though (like all (public) **properties MUST be in a static class**). **At design-time everything works** and VS can resolve the bindings (if the datacontext is set in xaml, NOT in cs). The bindings even ***update*** once to their default value at startup, but **NOT when the property source changed**.

---

**TLDR;
read the bold text :)**

---

**Code:**

**[Public static class]**
here the property is set by external code at runtime

```cs
public static class StaticClass
{
    public static string ExampleProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewModel.Instance.ExampleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ViewModel.Instance.ExampleProperty != value) ViewModel.Instance.ExampleProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**[ViewModel]**
a singleton class that holds the non-static backing field for the static properties in the class above and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```cs
internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private static ViewModel _instance = null;
    internal static ViewModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance is null) _instance = new();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private static string _exampleProperty { get; set; } = "Pls work"; 

    public string ExampleProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _exampleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _exampleProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (propertyName is not null) PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**[Xaml example binding]**

```xml
<Button Content="{Binding ExampleProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

**[MainWindow.cs]**
obviously a test project so this just changes the `ExampleProperty` to a random number on the `Button.Click` event

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Random random = new();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = ViewModel.Instance;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        StaticClass.ExampleProperty = random.Next(0, 69).ToString();
    }
}
```

so what am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you set that the Singleton instance named `Instance` to the DataContext?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Why is Singleton considered an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12755539/1136211)

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Content Binding has no effect. UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: Also be aware that it is possible to bind directly to static properties of a static class, even with change notification, thus eliminating the need for a singleton. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41823852/1136211

Comment: @emoacht Because i'm stupid and i was testing some stuff in the hopes of not having to make a stack overflow post :), so I didn't notice when copy pasting the code (so I did have it set to ```ViewModel.Instance``` originally) I'll update the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment on the question:

```
Also be aware that it is possible to bind directly to static properties of a static class, even with change notification, thus eliminating the need for a singleton. See e.g. here: stackoverflow.com/a/41823852/1136211
```

(and answer) I've had success with both a static and a non-static binding (FINALLY...).

### **For binding UI to a static class**

**The static class:**

```cs
public static class StaticClass
{
    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

    #region Properties

    public static string _exampleProperty = "Default value";
    public static string ExampleProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _exampleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_exampleProperty != value)
            {
                _exampleProperty = value;
                OnStaticPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**How to bind to UI:**

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:StaticClass.ExampleProperty)}"/>
```

**How to set the property:**

```cs
StaticClass.ExampleProperty = "New value that automatically updates the UI :)";
```

### **For binding UI to a non-static class**

Use the code from the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

assigns a different instance of the ViewModel class to the DataContext than the one returned from `ViewModel.Instance`, so that

```
StaticClass.ExampleProperty = random.Next(0, 69).ToString();
```

does not affect the DataContext. You should have assigned

```
DataContext = ViewModel.Instance;
```

Your ViewModel class does however not implement the singleton pattern correctly - it would have to avoid the creation of more than one instance, e.g. by declaring a private constructor.

---

The view does not need to use the singleton aspect of the view model at all. In order to access the current view model instance, cast the DataContext:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    ViewModel vm = (ViewModel)btn.DataContext;
    vm.ExampleProperty = random.Next(0, 69).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s) I already learned more about bindings than I did from the MSDN documentation :). It still doesn't work though. I set ```MainWindow.DataContext``` to ```new ViewModel()``` (and removed the nonsense singleton garbage),  implemented your ```Button_Click``` method and removed the ```UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged```. What am I doing wrong or is my VS just cursed. I'll go take a shower now and freshen up a bit, I've been working on this project for almost 24h straight now. Maybe I'll get a brainwave in the shower, and then I'll try your solution from scratch. XD

Comment: Be aware that `_exampleProperty` should not be static. Declare it as a field like this: `private string _exampleProperty = "Pls work";`. Also note that `if (propertyName is not null)` in OnPropertyChanged is wrong. Passing `null` as property name is a valid use case.